# Proper way to extract specific React child element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have the following component in React:

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormGroupProps, FormLabel, FormText, FormTextProps } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { FormLabelOwnProps } from 'react-bootstrap/esm/FormLabel';

interface TextInputProps {
    className?: string,
    value?: string,
    placeholder?: string,
    disabled?: boolean,
    containerProps?: FormGroupProps
    onChange: (value: string) => void
}

const TextInput: FunctionComponent<TextInputProps> & {
    Label: FunctionComponent<LabelProps>,
    Note: FunctionComponent<NoteProps>
} = (props) => {

    return (
        <FormGroup {...props.containerProps} >

            {/* Label Child Here */}
            
            <FormControl className={props.className} disabled={props.disabled} value={props.value} placeholder={props.placeholder} as='input' type='text' onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)} />

            {/* Note Child Here */}

        </FormGroup>
    );
}

// Input label
interface LabelProps extends FormLabelOwnProps {
    text: string
}
const Label: FunctionComponent<LabelProps> = (props: LabelProps) => {
    return (
        <FormLabel {...props} >{props.text}</FormLabel>
    );
}
TextInput.Label = Label;

// Input note
interface NoteProps extends FormTextProps {
    text: string
}
const Note: FunctionComponent<NoteProps> = (props: NoteProps) => {
    return (
        <FormText {...props} >{props.text}</FormText>
    );
}
TextInput.Note = Note;

export default TextInput;
```

I want to place the Label and Note subcomponents in specific places of the parent. What is the correct way to figure out which child in `props.children` corresponds to which subcomponent? I want to be able to pass any variation of children. (i.e. No Label or Note, Label only, Note only, or both)

My initial thought was to use `React.Children.forEach` or `.map` and check the key of the child. But with the `React.ReactNode` type being so broad, I'm not sure the best way to accomplish what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
import React, { FunctionComponent } from "react";
import {
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormGroupProps,
  FormLabel,
  FormText,
  FormTextProps
} from "react-bootstrap";
import { FormLabelOwnProps } from "react-bootstrap/esm/FormLabel";
import NavbarToggle from "react-bootstrap/esm/NavbarToggle";

interface TextInputProps {
  className?: string;
  value?: string;
  placeholder?: string;
  disabled?: boolean;
  containerProps?: FormGroupProps;
  onChange: (value: string) => void;
}

function isReactElement(arg: any): arg is React.ReactElement {
  return arg.hasOwnProperty("type");
}

const Label: FunctionComponent<LabelProps> = (props: LabelProps) => {
  return <FormLabel {...props}>{props.text}</FormLabel>;
};

const Note: FunctionComponent<NoteProps> = (props: NoteProps) => {
  return <FormText {...props}>{props.text}</FormText>;
};

const TextInput: FunctionComponent<TextInputProps> & {
  Label: FunctionComponent<LabelProps>;
  Note: FunctionComponent<NoteProps>;
} = (props) => {
  const childrenArray = React.Children.toArray(props.children);
  // label will be the label child (if set) or undefined (if no label child)
  const label = childrenArray.find(
    (child) => isReactElement(child) && child.type === Label
  );
  // the same holds for note
  const note = childrenArray.find(
    (child) => isReactElement(child) && child.type === Note
  );
  return (
    <FormGroup {...props.containerProps}>
      {label}

      <FormControl
        className={props.className}
        disabled={props.disabled}
        value={props.value}
        placeholder={props.placeholder}
        as="input"
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => props.onChange(e.target.value)}
      />

      {note}
    </FormGroup>
  );
};

// Input label
interface LabelProps extends FormLabelOwnProps {
  text: string;
}

TextInput.Label = Label;

// Input note
interface NoteProps extends FormTextProps {
  text: string;
}

TextInput.Note = Note;

export default TextInput;
```

This should allow you to handle all combinations of note, label, label+note, ...

Working codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-glitter-wu8fb?file=/src/MyComponent.tsx

Comment: Property 'type' does not exist on type 'ReactChild | ReactFragment | ReactPortal'. Is there a good typescript way of determining and casting the type without using `any`? (Also, you have a typo in const chil**d**renArray)

Comment: I am updating my answer with a complete example

Comment: Marking this as the correct answer as it answers for my specific question, but will keep in mind the alternative structure of passing the components as props instead.

Answer (score 0):

Is it required to pass the sub-components as children? Maybe another property would be suit this use case better. It would also enforce, that only one Label und only one Note is passed.

Comment: Required? Not necessarily, but I think the child structure is cleaner when consuming the component instead of passing everything in through props.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest restructuring things. Render props is meant only for one piece of element which is delegated to the caller. You have multiple elements so why even try doing anything with children? Now if there is a way, which is learning for me, and I want to know about it.

Check this to see a sample of how I would go about it. Considering what you already are trying to do,

```
import { ReactNode } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

interface MainCompProps{
  text: string;
  subComp1: ReactNode; // could use another type probably
  subComp2: ReactNode; // could use another type probably
}

const Comp1 = () => {
  return <div>Foo</div>;
}

const Comp2 = () => {
  return <div>Bar</div>;
}

const MainComp = (props: MainCompProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {props.subComp1}
      <div>{props.text}</div>
      {props.subComp2}
    </div>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <MainComp text={'hellooo'} subComp1={<Comp1/>} subComp2={<Comp2/>} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

This is a plain sample and there are some other considerations to keep in mind.

Another option is to restructure things so that you don't pass around components as props and keep them isolated. React is declarative, after all.